# Can class B/AB power amplifiers be used for AM modulation

Tags: rf, power-amplifier

Just wondering if class B/AB power amplifiers are 'linear' enough to be used in cases where the input is AM modulated?

I'm specifically referring to single transistor class B/AB mode.

Comment: yeah sure, why not?

Comment: Class AB and class B amplifiers are both linear amplification schemes, which can be used for amplifying AM (and for amplifying baseband if complimentary amplifiers are used).  Why don't you _edit your question_ to give an example of the circuit you're using, or explain the source of your confusion about why these _linear_ amplifiers may not be linear enough for AM?

Answer (score 0):

Class B was once used for RF due to higher efficiency in transformer-coupled full wave amplifiers.  I believe Class C is more popular now.

The zero-crossing distortion creates harmonics that were attenuated by filters but Class B does not prevent any previous modulation from being linear.

Comment: "I believe Class C is more popular now".  Yes, but it's a nonlinear amplifying process; it's not something that you could run AM into and get the same-but-bigger AM out.  Where class C amplifiers are used in AM signal generation, they're part of a high-power amplify-and-modulate stage.

Comment: Or adding AM over FM